# dispdiag syntax in C#

Tags: c#

can anyone please help how to call dispdiag using C#. When i am using the below code, an exception was caught with description "The system cannot find the file specified".

```
string commandPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "dispdiag.exe");
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(commandPath);
psInfo.Verb = "runas";

        try
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(psInfo);
            p.WaitForExit();
            //return "Try Done";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //return e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: did you watch `commandPath` and see the path given there has a file?

Comment: yes i have checked it.. That folder has dispdiag.exe. As the file is present in System32, i was not able to access it seems.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Are you in a 32 bit machine? or 64 bit machine? did you try run as admin? Whats the cpu version you are trying to build your app 32bit/64bit/anycpu?

Comment: i am in 64bit OS. Opened my VS in admin only. Built my app any cpu

Comment: I am just guesssing, could you try building you app in 32 bit and launch it separately by run as admin and see

Comment: hey carbinecoder... Thanks a lot.. i found the issue. When a new project is created, VS is setting the Prefer 32-bit as true. I removed it and it worked.